# List of all measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurement-theory

Let Ω be a four-element set (elements do not matter).

How can I find a list of all measures µ: P(Ω)→ N, for which µ(Ω) = 7, where P(Ω) is Power set of Ω.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just equivalent to set of all $4$-tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ in $\Bbb N$ such that $a+b+c+d=7$. We only need to assign integer values to the singletons and the measure is determined uniquely. It's quite easy to enumerate these; we will have $\binom{10}{7}$ many of them, by classic [combinatiorial facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).